# Loop calculations with random numbers

Tags: random

Given a function f

```
f=f[x,y,z]
```

I would like to compute f for different random values of x,y and z greater than 0

```
x:=RandomReal[n]; y:=RandomReal[n]; z:=RandomReal[n]
```

say 20 times, and show them as a set, each value of `x,y,z` and `f`, I mean something like `{x,y,z,f}`. I tried

```
x:=RandomReal[n]; y:=RandomReal[n]; z:=RandomReal[n]
Do[Print[f[x,y,z]],20]
```

but it didnt work. As I said, each values of x,y and z must be different, in general.

Comment: You didn't specify a value for `n`

Comment: My mistake, let us say `n=10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
n = 5
data = RandomReal[n, {20, 3}]
Map[{Sequence @@ #, f @@ #} &, data]
```

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Other ways:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := z + y + z
r = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}];

r /. a : {_, _, _} :> Join[a, {f @@ a}]
r /. a : {_, _, _} :> Append[a, f @@ a]
MapThread[Append, {r, f @@@ r}]
```

Comment: It works nicely too. Thanks

Comment: OK, that last one is pretty cool.